# How can I fix DRIVER_VERIFIER_DMA_VIOLATION crashes on my Windows 10 PC?

Tags: windows-10, bsod

Lately, I've been experiencing a lot of crashes (BSODs) on my Windows 10 PC. The 'Stop code' is DRIVER_VERIFIER_DMA_VIOLATION. However, I am not running Driver Verifier. How can I fix my PC?

Comment: Post some (zipped) minidumps from `C:\Windows\minidump`.

Comment: Yes, you need to upload minidump / memory dump. Using Windbg tool to capture some information about BSOD.